# regex for search text in string

Tags: javascript, regex

How to use regex to get the text in ()? 
for example:

```
input: test("abc")  output: "abc"
input: test("ab)c")  output: "ab)c"
input: test("ab)c" + "asd")  output: "ab)c" + "asd"
input: test("ab)c" + "uni()t").test  output: "ab)c" + "uni()t"
input: test("ab)c").split("/")  output: "ab)c"
```

Comment: show the **expected** output

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const input = ['test("abc")', 'test("ab)c")', 'test("ab)c" + "asd")', 'test("ab)c" + "uni()t").test', 'test("ab)c").split("/")']

const getBracket = data => ((data + ' ').match(/\((.*?)\)(?=(?:\.|\s))/) || ['',''])[1]

for (const testData of input) {
  console.log(`input: ${testData} output: ${getBracket(testData)}`)
}
```